# Failed to execute goal org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:4.2.1:bundle (default-bundle) on project HdrHistogram

Tags: java, maven, hdrhistogram

While trying to build https://github.com/HdrHistogram/HdrHistogram I am getting an error with the `maven-bundle-plugin` when running the command `mvn clean install -DskipTests`

I installed maven from homebrew for Mac. I'm wondering if the problem is being caused by a conflict in the Maven Java version and my local Java version?

### Maven Version

```bash
➜ mvn --version                                                                                                     
Apache Maven 3.8.6 (84538c9988a25aec085021c365c560670ad80f63)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.8.6/libexec
Java version: 18.0.2.1, vendor: Homebrew, runtime: /usr/local/Cellar/openjdk/18.0.2.1/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "12.5.1", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

### Java Version

```
➜ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_322"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-8.322.06.1 (build 1.8.0_322-b06)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-8.322.06.1 (build 25.322-b06, mixed mode)
```

### Error

```bash
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:4.2.1:bundle (default-bundle) on project HdrHistogram: Internal error in maven-bundle-plugin: ConcurrentModificationException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:4.2.1:bundle (default-bundle) on project HdrHistogram: Internal error in maven-bundle-plugin
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to reproduce the issue, but on `Windows`:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:4.2.1:bundle (default-bundle) on project HdrHistogram: Internal error in maven-bundle-plugin: ConcurrentModificationException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:4.2.1:bundle (default-bundle) on project HdrHistogram: Internal error in maven-bundle-plugin
```

with the same [Java](https://github.com/corretto/corretto-8/releases/tag/8.322.06.1) & [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi) versions as you mentioned:

```
E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram>mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.8.6 (84538c9988a25aec085021c365c560670ad80f63)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.8.6
Java version: 1.8.0_322, vendor: Amazon.com Inc., runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_322\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1251
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"

E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram>java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_322"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-8.322.06.1 (build 1.8.0_322-b06)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-8.322.06.1 (build 25.322-b06, mixed mode)
```

but I'm getting `'Build success'` in the output:

```
E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram>mvn clean install -DskipTests
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Inspecting build with total of 1 modules...
[INFO] Installing Nexus Staging features:
[INFO]   ... total of 1 executions of maven-deploy-plugin replaced with nexus-staging-maven-plugin
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------< org.hdrhistogram:HdrHistogram >--------------------
[INFO] Building HdrHistogram 2.1.13-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] -------------------------------[ bundle ]-------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ HdrHistogram ---
[INFO] Deleting E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-replacer-plugin:1.4.0:replace (default) @ HdrHistogram ---
[INFO] Replacement run on 1 file.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.3.0:resources (default-resources) @ HdrHistogram ---
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\src\main\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) @ HdrHistogram ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 54 source files to E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.3.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ HdrHistogram ---
[INFO] Copying 5 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ HdrHistogram ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5:test (default-test) @ HdrHistogram ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-bundle-plugin:4.2.1:bundle (default-bundle) @ HdrHistogram ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-javadoc-plugin:3.3.1:jar (attach-javadocs) @ HdrHistogram ---
[WARNING]
Loading source file E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\src\main\java\org\HdrHistogram\Base64Helper.java...
Loading source file E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\src\main\java\org\HdrHistogram\ConcurrentDoubleHistogram.java...
Loading source file E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\src\main\java\org\HdrHistogram\ConcurrentHistogram.java...
Loading source file E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\src\main\java\org\HdrHistogram\DoubleAllValuesIterator.java...
Loading source file E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\src\main\java\org\HdrHistogram\DoubleHistogram.java...
Loading source file E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\src\main\java\org\HdrHistogram\EncodableHistogram.java...
Loading source file E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\src\main\java\org\HdrHistogram\Histogram.java...
Loading source file E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\src\main\java\org\HdrHistogram\HistogramLogWriter.java...
Loading source file E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\src\main\java\org\HdrHistogram\IntCountsHistogram.java...
Loading source file E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\src\main\java\org\HdrHistogram\IntervalHistogramProvider.java...
Loading source file E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\src\main\java\org\HdrHistogram\LinearIterator.java...
Loading source file E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\src\main\java\org\HdrHistogram\LogarithmicIterator.java...
Loading source file E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\src\main\java\org\HdrHistogram\package-info.java...
Loading source file E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\src\main\java\org\HdrHistogram\packedarray\AbstractPackedArrayContext.java...
Loading source file E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\src\main\java\org\HdrHistogram\packedarray\ConcurrentPackedLongArray.java...
Loading source file E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\src\main\java\org\HdrHistogram\packedarray\PackedLongArray.java...
Loading source file E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\src\main\java\org\HdrHistogram\packedarray\ResizeException.java...
Loading source file E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\src\main\java\org\HdrHistogram\PackedConcurrentDoubleHistogram.java...
Loading source file E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\src\main\java\org\HdrHistogram\PackedConcurrentHistogram.java...
Loading source file E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\src\main\java\org\HdrHistogram\PackedDoubleHistogram.java...
Loading source file E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\src\main\java\org\HdrHistogram\PackedHistogram.java...
Loading source file E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\src\main\java\org\HdrHistogram\PercentileIterator.java...
Loading source file E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\src\main\java\org\HdrHistogram\RecordedValuesIterator.java...
Loading source file E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\src\main\java\org\HdrHistogram\Recorder.java...
Loading source file E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\src\main\java\org\HdrHistogram\ShortCountsHistogram.java...
Loading source file E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\src\main\java\org\HdrHistogram\SingleWriterDoubleRecorder.java...
Loading source file E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\src\main\java\org\HdrHistogram\SingleWriterRecorder.java...
Loading source file E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\src\main\java\org\HdrHistogram\SynchronizedDoubleHistogram.java...
Loading source file E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\src\main\java\org\HdrHistogram\SynchronizedHistogram.java...
Loading source file E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\src\main\java\org\HdrHistogram\ValueRecorder.java...
Loading source file E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\src\main\java\org\HdrHistogram\Version.java...
Loading source file E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\src\main\java\org\HdrHistogram\WriterReaderPhaser.java...
Loading source file E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\src\main\java\org\HdrHistogram\ZigZagEncoding.java...
Loading source files for package org.HdrHistogram...
Loading source files for package org.HdrHistogram.packedarray...
Constructing Javadoc information...
Standard Doclet version 1.8.0_322
Building tree for all the packages and classes...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\AbstractHistogram.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\AbstractHistogram.AllValues.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\AbstractHistogram.LinearBucketValues.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\AbstractHistogram.LogarithmicBucketValues.html...
Generating 
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\AllValuesIterator.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\AtomicHistogram.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\ConcurrentDoubleHistogram.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\ConcurrentHistogram.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\DoubleAllValuesIterator.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\DoubleHistogram.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\DoubleHistogram.AllValues.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\DoubleHistogram.LinearBucketValues.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\DoubleHistogram.LogarithmicBucketValues.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\DoubleHistogram.Percentiles.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\DoubleHistogram.RecordedValues.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\DoubleHistogramIterationValue.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\DoubleLinearIterator.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\DoubleLogarithmicIterator.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\DoublePercentileIterator.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\DoubleRecordedValuesIterator.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\DoubleRecorder.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\DoubleValueRecorder.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\EncodableHistogram.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\Histogram.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\HistogramIterationValue.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\HistogramLogProcessor.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\HistogramLogReader.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\HistogramLogScanner.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\HistogramLogScanner.EncodableHistogramSupplier.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\HistogramLogScanner.EventHandler.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\HistogramLogWriter.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\IntCountsHistogram.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\IntervalHistogramProvider.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\LinearIterator.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\LogarithmicIterator.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\PackedConcurrentDoubleHistogram.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\PackedConcurrentHistogram.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\PackedDoubleHistogram.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\PackedHistogram.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\PercentileIterator.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\RecordedValuesIterator.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\Recorder.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\ShortCountsHistogram.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\SingleWriterDoubleRecorder.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\SingleWriterRecorder.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\SynchronizedDoubleHistogram.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\SynchronizedHistogram.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\ValueRecorder.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\WriterReaderPhaser.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\packedarray\ConcurrentPackedLongArray.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\packedarray\IterationValue.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\packedarray\PackedArrayRecorder.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\packedarray\PackedArraySingleWriterRecorder.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\packedarray\PackedLongArray.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\overview-frame.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\package-frame.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\package-summary.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\package-tree.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\packedarray\package-frame.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\packedarray\package-summary.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\packedarray\package-tree.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\constant-values.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\serialized-form.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\AbstractHistogram.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\AbstractHistogram.Percentiles.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\AbstractHistogram.LinearBucketValues.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\AbstractHistogram.LogarithmicBucketValues.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\AbstractHistogram.RecordedValues.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\AbstractHistogram.AllValues.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\AllValuesIterator.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\AtomicHistogram.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\ConcurrentDoubleHistogram.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\ConcurrentHistogram.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\DoubleAllValuesIterator.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\DoubleHistogram.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\DoubleHistogram.Percentiles.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\DoubleHistogram.LinearBucketValues.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\DoubleHistogram.LogarithmicBucketValues.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\DoubleHistogram.RecordedValues.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\DoubleHistogram.AllValues.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\DoubleHistogramIterationValue.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\DoubleLinearIterator.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\DoubleLogarithmicIterator.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\DoublePercentileIterator.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\DoubleRecordedValuesIterator.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\DoubleRecorder.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\DoubleValueRecorder.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\EncodableHistogram.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\Histogram.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\HistogramIterationValue.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\HistogramLogProcessor.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\HistogramLogReader.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\HistogramLogScanner.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\HistogramLogScanner.EncodableHistogramSupplier.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\HistogramLogScanner.EventHandler.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\HistogramLogWriter.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\IntCountsHistogram.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\IntervalHistogramProvider.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\LinearIterator.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\LogarithmicIterator.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\packedarray\class-use\ConcurrentPackedLongArray.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\packedarray\class-use\IterationValue.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\packedarray\class-use\PackedArrayRecorder.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\packedarray\class-use\PackedArraySingleWriterRecorder.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\packedarray\class-use\PackedLongArray.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\PackedConcurrentDoubleHistogram.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\PackedConcurrentHistogram.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\PackedDoubleHistogram.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\PackedHistogram.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\PercentileIterator.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\RecordedValuesIterator.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\Recorder.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\ShortCountsHistogram.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\SingleWriterDoubleRecorder.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\SingleWriterRecorder.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\SynchronizedDoubleHistogram.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\SynchronizedHistogram.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\ValueRecorder.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\WriterReaderPhaser.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\WriterReaderPhaser.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\ValueRecorder.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\SynchronizedHistogram.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\SynchronizedDoubleHistogram.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\SingleWriterRecorder.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\SingleWriterDoubleRecorder.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\ShortCountsHistogram.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\Recorder.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\RecordedValuesIterator.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\PercentileIterator.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\PackedHistogram.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\PackedDoubleHistogram.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\PackedConcurrentHistogram.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\PackedConcurrentDoubleHistogram.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\LogarithmicIterator.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\LinearIterator.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\IntervalHistogramProvider.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\IntCountsHistogram.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\HistogramLogWriter.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\HistogramLogScanner.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\HistogramLogScanner.EncodableHistogramSupplier.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\HistogramLogScanner.EventHandler.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\HistogramLogReader.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\HistogramLogProcessor.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\HistogramIterationValue.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\Histogram.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\EncodableHistogram.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\DoubleValueRecorder.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\DoubleRecorder.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\DoubleRecordedValuesIterator.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\DoublePercentileIterator.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\DoubleLogarithmicIterator.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\DoubleLinearIterator.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\DoubleHistogramIterationValue.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\DoubleHistogram.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\DoubleHistogram.Percentiles.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\DoubleHistogram.LinearBucketValues.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\DoubleHistogram.LogarithmicBucketValues.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\DoubleHistogram.RecordedValues.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\DoubleHistogram.AllValues.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\DoubleAllValuesIterator.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\ConcurrentHistogram.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\AtomicHistogram.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\AbstractHistogram.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\AbstractHistogram.Percentiles.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\AbstractHistogram.LinearBucketValues.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\AbstractHistogram.LogarithmicBucketValues.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\class-use\AbstractHistogram.RecordedValues.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\packedarray\class-use\IterationValue.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\packedarray\class-use\ConcurrentPackedLongArray.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\package-use.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\org\HdrHistogram\packedarray\package-use.html...
Building index for all the packages and classes...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\overview-tree.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\index-all.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\deprecated-list.html...
Building index for all classes...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\allclasses-frame.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\allclasses-noframe.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\index.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\overview-summary.html...
Generating E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\apidocs\help-doc.html...
[INFO] Building jar: E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\HdrHistogram-2.1.13-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-source-plugin:3.2.1:jar-no-fork (attach-sources) @ HdrHistogram ---
[INFO] Building jar: E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\HdrHistogram-2.1.13-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:copy (copy-installed) @ HdrHistogram ---
[INFO] Configured Artifact: org.hdrhistogram:HdrHistogram:2.1.13-SNAPSHOT:bundle
[INFO] Copying HdrHistogram-2.1.13-SNAPSHOT.jar to E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\HdrHistogram.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:3.0.1:install (default-install) @ HdrHistogram ---
[INFO] Installing E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\pom.xml to C:\Users\invzbl3\.m2\repository\org\hdrhistogram\HdrHistogram\2.1.13-SNAPSHOT\HdrHistogram-2.1.13-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] Installing E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\HdrHistogram-2.1.13-SNAPSHOT.jar to C:\Users\invzbl3\.m2\repository\org\hdrhistogram\HdrHistogram\2.1.13-SNAPSHOT\HdrHistogram-2.1.13-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\HdrHistogram-2.1.13-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar to C:\Users\invzbl3\.m2\repository\org\hdrhistogram\HdrHistogram\2.1.13-SNAPSHOT\HdrHistogram-2.1.13-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar
[INFO] Installing E:\IdeaProject\HdrHistogram\target\HdrHistogram-2.1.13-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar to C:\Users\invzbl3\.m2\repository\org\hdrhistogram\HdrHistogram\2.1.13-SNAPSHOT\HdrHistogram-2.1.13-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-bundle-plugin:4.2.1:install (default-install) @ HdrHistogram ---
[INFO] Installing org/hdrhistogram/HdrHistogram/2.1.13-SNAPSHOT/HdrHistogram-2.1.13-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Writing OBR metadata
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  20.792 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-10-03T03:58:19+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```